# Convert std::stringstream to const char** without memory allocation

Tags: c++, opencl, std, stringstream

From what I understand, a `std::stringstream` is represented internally not as an `std::string` but rather as a set of `std::string` instances. (correct me if I am wrong).

I have data represented as an `std::stringstream` and I want to pass it to a C function (`clCreateProgramWithSource` from OpenCL) that expects the data as an array of arrays of chars. (`const char**)`.

Is there some way to do this *without* first creating a single string that holds the entire content of the stringstream, for example in the following way:

```
std::string tmp1 = my_stringstream.str();
const char* tmp2 = tmp1.c_str();
const char** tmp3 = &tmp2;
```

**EDIT**

Follow-up question:

If this is *not* possible, is there some alternative to `std::stringstream`, inheriting from `std::ostream`, that allows this low level access?

Comment: The implementation of `stringstream` is not specified. For C++, the internal `streambuf` object would be a useful low-level point of access, but for C interop your code is basically as good as it can be.

Comment: @KerrekSB OK, I was thinking that there should be some way around it, that would at least work for a standard `stringstream` implementation. With fallback to the above code in other cases.

Comment: As fallback, you can derive from `ostream` or `streambuf` to implement your own stream, if concatenating and splitting stream _is actually a bottleneck_. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490499/how-can-i-derive-my-own-stream-from-a-standard-stream)

Comment: You are are trying to optimize at the entirely wrong level. Copying a string costs *literally*  nothing compared to what `clCreateProgramWithSource` does. It's like removing a fly from an elephant and hope it will lose weight.

Comment: @Lol4t0 Thanks for the pointer on how to implement a stream. I will consider it, *if it actually turns out to be a bottle neck* as you rightly point out.

Comment: @BoPersson I am 100 % sure you are right that the overhead in `clCreateProgramWithSource`. In fact, I've tested building up LLVM intermediate code directly instead of code generation and compilation with Clang, only to realize that there was virtually no difference in performance. And my OpenCL implementation uses Clang/LLVM afaik. But I'm still interested in the `std::stringstream` to `char**` conversion for C++/C interop in general.

Comment: I'm not sure how correct it is, but I did this: `stream.str().c_str()`

Answer (score 1):

By getting the streambuf of the stringstream we can explicitly set the buffer it should use:

```
#include <sstream>

constexpr size_t buffer_size = 512;

void dummy_clCreateProgramWithSource(const char **strings) {}

int main () {
  char * ss_buffer = new char[buffer_size];
  std::stringstream filestr; // TODO initialize from file
  filestr.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(ss_buffer,buffer_size);
  const char** extra_indirection = const_cast<const char **>(&ss_buffer);
  dummy_clCreateProgramWithSource(extra_indirection);
  return 0;
}
```

Note the const_cast that tells what may be a lie; we are promising OpenCL that we won't write to the stringstream after calling clCreateProgramWithSource.